# Python create multiple dictionaries from values ​read from a list

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have the following list of values: Numbers = [1,2,3,4].
Is it possible to create a dictionary with the same name as the values ​​contained in the list?

Example: dictionary_1 = {}
dictionary_2 = {}
....
dictionary_Number.. {}

I would like to create these dictionaries automatically, without creating them manually, reading the numbers contained in the list

Comment: You could use a list of dictionaries. In this case your dictionary_1 = {}, would be dictionaries[0] = {}. Does this cover what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuild functions and remember that a dictionary needs a tuble (key & value):

- [Python Dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
- [Python Dictionary fromkeys() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_fromkeys.asp)

Example-Code:

```
Numbers = [1,2,3,4]
Numbers_dict = dict.fromkeys(Numbers,"dict_value")
print(Numbers_dict)
```

This will output:

```
{'1': 'dict_value', '2': 'dict_value', '3': 'dict_value', '4': 'dict_value'}
```

If you want to get a single dictonaries for each list-value, you first have to create for each list-value an empty variable.
After this you have to fill this empty vairables within a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the keyword `exec` in python. Here is an example of your solution,

```
List = [1, 2,3]
for ele in List:
    dic = f"Dictionary_{ele}"
    exec(dic+" = {}")
print(Dictionary_1, Dictionary_2, Dictionary_3, sep='\n')
```

you may use it according to you, but the disadvantage for it is that you will need to use `exec` every time you need to use it or you must know what would be the name outcome of the first use of `exec` ...

I hope I helped...